# How to put textview below the imageview in listview?

Tags: android, xml, listview, textview, imageview

I want to put my textview under the imageview in listview when I am trying to use the relative it give some error so I use the linearlayout but I can't put the textview under the imageview can you please help me thank you in advance?

xml  listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bacground"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

xml in listview_layout:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

<Textview
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my code:

```
        OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent b_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PicSelectActivity.class);
            startActivity(b_intent);

            // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
            LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) container;
            // Getting the inner Linear Layout
            LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = (LinearLayout) linearLayoutParent
                    .getChildAt(1);
            // Getting the Country TextView
            TextView tvCountry = (TextView) linearLayoutChild.getChildAt(0);

            Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("getFrame", tvCountry.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();

        }
    };
    // Setting the item click listener for the listview
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
```

Comment: what you actually want to do?

Comment: i just want to put my textview below the imageview

Comment: you want your textview in center below the imageview

Comment: `when im trying to use the relative it give some error` What error?

Answer (score 1):

Just do to your root layout

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the **root linear layout orientation to vertical** and remove the other unnecessary linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Above you write a long xml but you write below code and achieve your goal. Use text view and set `android:drawableTop` for image and `android:text` for text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

***check this* **

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/race_entrant"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingRight="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="2dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLeft"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#E0EAF1"
    android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:paddingRight="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="2dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/imgJockey"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/txtEntrantNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/entrant_number"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:cacheColorHint="#E0EAF1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Their is no need to use two linearlayout. one extra id will be created in resource file. Not efficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use this

```
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

as this is part of RelativeLayout not LinearLayout.

below code will solve your problem. try this.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flag"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello" />


            <Textview
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use `android:orientation="vertical`" to your root `LinearLayout`.

**2.** Remove child `LinearLayout` and update `TextView` and `ImageView` attribute as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="This is a sample text." />

</LinearLayout>
```

**3.** In your `onItemClick()` method try this:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container,
            int position, long id) {

        Intent b_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                PicSelectActivity.class);
        startActivity(b_intent);

        // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
        LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) container;

        // Getting the Country TextView
        TextView tvCountry = (TextView) linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(1);

        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("getFrame", tvCountry.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();

    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~